# How can I hide the salt code in Flash or Java?

Tags: java, flash, security, hash, salt

I need to be able to transmit data from a Flash browser application to a PHP file on a web server, both securing and validating the data whilst and at the same time trying to prevent unauthorised creation of the message. (I want to try and ensure that the message comes from the application, not a user sending a message via another means).

In a C++ application I would Salt the data, and send the hash of the data along with it, and then validate the hash against the data to ensure integrity and source.

However, in Flash (& Java), applications can be decompiled so that the source code is viewable. So if I used this method, someone could (relatively) easily find the salt, and then create a 'valid' message of their own to send outside of the application.

Is there any way I can 'hide' this salt code to help secure the transmission? Yes, I know there are code obfuscators, but they don't fully hide the code, just add another layer.

Or is there another method entirely that could be used to transmit data and validate the source & content at the PHP end?

Comment: C++ binaries can also be decompiled. You can't "hide" something inside a binary. Use SSL for such means and make sure the server certificate is valid.

Comment: I agree with the above, but even so SSL only protects the communication from client to server. Even with SLL the traffic a client creates can be modified by users.

Comment: SSL is not 100% safe if you have a man in the middle who manipulates the first handshake then he can look into and manipulate any data sent. but the timing has to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do, the code to do it will be there in the client, and all you can do is obfuscate. If you, as Tomasz says, were to have the client authenticate with the server and then receive a salt (or a key from a asymmetric key-pair) you still need to have all the code necessary to connect to that server in the client. So by design, no matter what you do, all the ingredients to do so has to be in the client, and thus on your "hackers" computer. It's just a question of much harder it would be for a hacker to understand it.

It's the same for all kinds of clients, no matter what language they're written in. If a DVD player can show a decrypted DVD disc on your TV, it has to have the key to decrypt it in memory, which you can find. This is why no-one has made perfect copy-protection :)

EDIT:
As all the others are saying. Off-the-shelf obfuscator is probably the best way to go, and you could make the client jump through some extra hoops first aswell.

EDIT2:
Turns out I didn't understand Tomasz correctly. If the user himself has the key to authenticate to the server in order to get the hash, that will indeed authenticate that the message was sent from the user, but still not from the application. If this is a matter of avoiding cheating then the hacker is probably already a customer (buying a product or making an account). If what you want is to authenticate the user, then it's a completely different matter, and that is quite possible. (with it's own problems of-course)

Comment: I meant letting authenticate by the user in front of the screen, so that no keys are in the application itself. If the keys were in the app, then there is really not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

There's no truly secure way to protect programs that run on the client. (C++ can also be decompiled by the way.) It's always going to be possible for users to run clients that have been hacked, and any encryption key will have to be present in the code in some form. You may be able to make it more difficult for casual hackers but that's it. Whatever you implement will amount to another form of obfuscation; you may as well look at the off-the-shelf obfuscators.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps first authenticate with the server, get a salt key from the server, then use it? This way users wanting to fake messages even if capable of decompiling the app would have to authenticate also.

Other than that - at some time you always need the password, hash, key (or whatever is needed to encrypt or validate data) available to the application and either you get it first from your server or embed in the application, which would be recognizable by decompilation.

**EDIT**

As others have pointed there is no 100% security, everything can be hacked, the point is to make it not too easy, to prevent casual hackers, that's all. So as Jim stated an off-the-shell obfuscator may be the best compromise.